# How to display system date minus 7 days within the <h> element?

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

I would like to display the current system date minus 7 days within the heading of a webpage.

```
 <h1>Is this article older than (7 days prior today's date)</h1>
```

How would I achieve displaying this in-line with the  element?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the javascript `Date` object. Be aware that the month index is 0 based...

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);
document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = "Is this article older than "+(d.getMonth() + 1)+"/"+d.getDate()+"/"+d.getFullYear();
```

```html
<h1 id='heading'></h1>
```